# Installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7, GRUB isn't boot manager

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

When I clicked "restart now" after installation (and after I tried out Ubuntu for a bit), I was expecting GRUB to come up right away where I could choose Windows 7 or Ubuntu 14.04.

However, Windows just booted automatically without any other options.

The installation was fine, no files were harmed.

Specs:

```
i5-4690k  
120GB 840 EVO (where windows 7 is installed):  
    100MB System (Primary)  
    111GB Boot, Page file, Crash dump (Primary)   
1TB WD Blue:  
    300MB Recovery Partition (Primary)  
    100MG EFI Partition (Primary)  
    831.62GB as D: drive on Windows (Primary)  
    20GB set as / in Ubuntu setup (Primary)  
    16GB set as swap in Ubuntu setup (Primary)  
    65.22GB set as /home in Ubuntu setup (Primary)
```

The first thing I noticed is that there is way more than 3 primary partitions... which might be a problem. If I partitioned them wrong I will re-allocate the Ubuntu (`E: or dev/sda5`) drive and re-install with the swap and `/home` as logical drives.

I also guess that having two disks with boot files being on a completely different disk from where the Ubuntu files were stored may be the problem.

I've used Ubuntu before, but it was always the only operating system. So I have no idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have EFI. In which case, this is a very simple fix:

1. Enter your BIOS settings. You can usually get in by hitting the <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F7</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, or the <kbd>Del</kbd> key. Check your computer's documentation for the specific key.
2. You want to navigate to the "Boot Order" menu.
3. Move "GRUB" to be beginning of the order, before the Windows Boot Manager.
4. Save and Quit from the BIOS.
5. Enjoy Ubuntu.

You may need to disable SecureBoot, however that is rather unlikely. There should be an option somewhere.